# Correct way to size content with vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

What is the correct way to handle this ? for example, in Tailwind you use `w-3/5` and `w-2/5` to set two divs with `60%` and `40%`.

In Vuetify i'm trying to accomplish this by making both divs `fluid` with a `max-width` of what I consider being the 60 and 40...

I know this probably is very bad, but I couldn't find another way to workaround this.
something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create v-container (fluid if you prefer). Inside of container create v-row. Inside of v-row you can create v-col elements. Vuetify grid is quite similar to bootstrap grid. It has 12-columns grid. So you can't divide 12 to 5 but you can make something very similar :)

Following link would help you to get used to the grid:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/

Comment: thank you, this is what i was looking for. It really is pretty similar, thanks again